# sticky footer on the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, footer

I know that there are tons of answer out there. I spent many many hours trying to figure out what it not working.

I want to have a sticky footer.
the html structure is like this

```
<body>
<div id=container>

  <div id=header>
  </div>

  <div id=body>
     <div id=left>
     </div>
     <div id=center>
     </div>
     <div  id=right>
     </div>
  </div>

 <div id=footer>
     </div>

</div>
</body>
```

and a link with the css and the content [link](http://jsfiddle.net/hvND6/)

Comment: http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/ There are *beyond* tons of answers here on Stack Overflow alone. Do some research before you ask a question.

Comment: http://www.cssstickyfooter.com

Answer (score 0):

Change your footer position from "absolute" to "fixed"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the footer always be at the bottom of the screen/window you can add the following to your css

```
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```